# The ionic start command fails for me with the following error on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js, cordova, ubuntu-14.04, ionic-framework

The ionic start command fails for me with the following error on Ubuntu 14.04 and need assistance in resolving the issue:

andrew@FinancialIndepence:~/WebstormProjects/stadiumStore/mobile$ ionic start myApp tabs
Creating Ionic app in folder /home/andrew/WebstormProjects/stadiumStore/mobile/myApp based on tabs project

Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip
[=============================] 100% 0.0s

Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs/archive/master.zip
[=============================] 100% 0.0s

Update config.xml
Initializing cordova project
Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.device" via plugin registry
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
SyntaxError: Unexpected token I
Internal routing error

Sorry, we cannot connect to the intended server.

We have just been notified of this problem. We will correct it as soon as possible.

Feel free to contact us if you have any questions: support@iriscouch.com

```
at Object.parse (native)
at RegClient.<anonymous> (/home/andrew/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:274:23)
at /home/andrew/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:251:7
at Gunzip.onEnd (zlib.js:167:5)
at Gunzip.emit (events.js:117:20)
at _stream_readable.js:944:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
Unable to add plugins. Perhaps your version of Cordova is too old. Try updating (npm install -g cordova), removing this project folder, and trying again. (CLI v1.3.0)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you still get the same error now?

Answer (score 0):

In the forums several people were saying that the plugins.cordova.io server was down.  Others say that trying a different version worked for them.

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-start-cli-errors/15468/4

I just ran the same command and had no trouble with it